# How do I convert from int to unsigned short int - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, int, unsigned

I am trying to get an integer from a plist and use it with `sin_port`. However `sin_port` requires an `unsigned short` and not an `int`  how do I convert an `int` to an `unsigned short int`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know objective-c but in plain C you can do something like

```
int value = 1234;
unsigned short sin_port = (unsigned short) value;
```